# assign different values to different entries of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to assign different values for `x` in the following list, in other words, say, `x=6` in the first entries assign , `x=6.1` in the 2nd, `x=6.2` in the 3rd and so on. How can this work be done?

```
{A1 x , A2 x^2 , A3 x^3}
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is a very poorly posed question. 1) " in the following list"; what following list -- I see no list. 2) What are A1, A2, and A3? I don't know how you expect to get answer. We are not psychics.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to generate `lists` for different values of `x`.

Assuming `A1`, `A2`, and `A3` are constants.

```
list = {A1 x, A2 x^2, A3 x^3};
listDiffXValues = list /. {x -> #} & /@ {6, 6.1, 6.2}
(*{{6 A1, 36 A2, 216 A3}, {6.1 A1, 37.21 A2, 226.981 A3}, 
{6.2 A1, 38.44 A2, 238.328 A3}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

I understood the question differently. I assumed you wanted to assign to each `x` in the first list a corresponding value from the other list in the order they show up?  if so, One way could be

```
ClearAll[x]
list = {A1 x, A2 x^2, A3 x^3};
values = {6, 6.1, 6.2};
Inner[Function[{r1, r2}, r1 /. x -> r2], list, values, List]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Excellent. very thanks.